# Using idFTP to upload files

Tags: delphi, uploading

I'm trying to upload file using the the idFTP component and have defined what I can see as the essential properties as such:

```
  FTPClient.Host  := tblFtpFTPHost.AsString;
  FTPClient.Username := tblFTPUsername.AsString;
  FTPClient.Password := tblFTPPassword.AsString;
  FTPClient.Port     := tblFTPPort.AsInteger;
```

However when I run the command -

```
  FTPClient.Connect;
```

It will fail with the following error message:

```
  Project Uploader.exe raised exception class EIdPortRequired with message ''.
```

Am I not providing the information to the correct properties? Do I need another component on my form to allow me to upload files?

I'm currently using Delphi XE as my IDE.

Thanks.

Comment: I have a small suspicion that you aren't telling the whole story here. The Indy code source code clearly indicates that the Port value is really 0. Please debug your code step by step and add a watch for the Port value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your port value is 0.
This is the only place where Indy throws this exception:

```
procedure TIdTCPClientCustom.Connect;
begin
  // Do not call Connected here, it will call CheckDisconnect
  if Connected then begin
    EIdAlreadyConnected.Toss(RSAlreadyConnected);
  end;

  if Host = '' then begin
    EIdHostRequired.Toss('');
  end;
  if Port = 0 then begin
    EIdPortRequired.Toss('');
  end;
 ...
```

Please check that the port value is not 0.

Comment: I have checked this and I am assigning the port. Looking at the code above, the idFTP component doesn't have a .connect event.

Comment: Like @whosrdaddy says, the ONLY way an `EIdPortRequired` exception can be raised is if you are assigning 0 to the `TIdFTP.Port` property. And yes, `TIdFTP` does have a published `OnConnected` event that is triggered just before `TIdTCPClientCustom.Connect()` exits, but DO NOT perform any FTP commands in that event, as `TIdFTP.Connect()` (which calls `TIdTCPClientCustom.Connect()` internally) is still running and not finished setting up the characteristics of the FTP session yet. Wait until `TIdFTP.Connect()` exits before you start issuing commands.

Comment: I consider empty exception messages to be a crap thing to do to people.  It should be EIdHostRequired.Toss(rsMustSetHostValue) where rsMustSetHostValue is a resource string or resource id const